# bash script using sed to substitute twice

Tags: sed

file1 contains:

```
first=stan
last=smith
```

I want to create file2 which contains

```
first=homer
last=simpson
```

script.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash
sed s/stan/$1/ file1 >tempfile
sed s/smith/$2/ tempfile >file2
rm tempfile
```

script.sh homer simpson does what I want.
Is there a better way to do this in a bash script without creating and deleting tempfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
$ s1="homer"
$ s2="simpson"
$ sed -e "s/stan/$s1/g" -e "s/smith/$s2/g" file1 > file2
$ cat file2
first=homer
last=simpson
```

As you can see the `-e` option is used to perform two different sed commands in the same line.

In a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e "s/stan/$1/g" -e "s/smith/$2/g" file1 > file2
```

Comment: This just updates `file1`, request `I want to create file2 which contains`

Answer (score 0):

Sed supports multiple expressions. So you can do something like:

```
sed -e "s/stan/$1/" -e "s/smith/$2/" file1 > file2
```

I also recommend to use double quotes to prevent [wordsplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: Single quotes tend to be better for sed arguments, as they remove the meaning of special characters. (Although here of course that would prevent expansion of `$1`.)